# NSTextField not responding

Tags: objective-c, nstextfield

I created an NSTextField in my code:

.h :

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
 IBOutlet NSTextField *numberOfConnectionsTextField;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTextField *numberOfConnectionsTextField;
```

.m :

```
@synthesize numberOfConnectionsTextField;
```

I change the value of the field here:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    [numberOfConnectionsTextField setStringValue:@"0"];

}
```

And the value successfully changes. However, when I try to the change the value here:

```
- (void)connectionNumber:(NSString *)number {

    [numberOfConnectionsTextField setStringValue:number];
    NSRunAlertPanel(@"", number, @"", @"", @"");

}
```

The NSTextField didn't change. BUT, the NSRunAlertPanel did trigger with the 'number' string correctly.

Any ideas? I can't seem to find what I did wrong...

Comment: I'd first guess that by the time you get to that second case your numberOfConnectionsTextField is nil.

Comment: How do I stop that from happening?

Comment: Well, first you find out if that's really what's happening.  Then, if so, you figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks quite good. There is no error, the first reason is always of not connecting the outlet to the object but as you are able to change in applicationDidFinishLaunching:, so that is not the issue here.

But You did not mentioned about "-(void)connectionNumber:(NSString *)" is this in the same class? or you have created same iboutlet in another class and missed something?

Or you manually released the outlet numberOfConnectionsTextField ? Please check if it is not null? like

```
if(numberOfConnectionsTextField){ 
    NSLog(@"Still exist") 
}
```

Another reason might be, from which method are you calling "-(void)connectionNumber:(NSString *)", many a times it is seen that people call set/get of outlet from init.

Please comment if you are doing every thing correct...

Comment: "-(void)connectionNumber:(NSString *)" is in the same class. But, it's being called from another class. Could this be the problem? I know that it's being called because the NSRunAlertPanel pops up with the 'number' nsstring.

Comment: did you alloc init it again?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably safer to use self.numberOfConnectionsTextField then the variable name numberOfConnectionsTextField alone. This kind of error happened to me when I first learn objective c. Some of the IBOutLet gone nil after a period of time.

Try to use self.variablename for strong , synthesize variable

Comment: Hey! I tried it - stil doesn't work :( thanks for the tip though!